# Flutter | Retrieve data from Firestore before to build a Widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database in *Firestore*. I want to retrieve a `List` from it before to build a `Widget` (screen). I don’t want to get it through an event like a `onTap`, `onPressed` or something similar. What’s the best solution to do that? I’m interested in a solution that uses `provider` package and in a solution that uses `StreamBuilder`. Perhaps exists a solution that is a mix of these two.

Thanks!

Comment: you may call the function in `initState`.

Comment: I need to retrieve data _before_ the `build()` method. How can I do it if in `initState()` I can’t use `await` keyword?

Comment: You want to retrieve the list and populate to listView or what ?

Comment: No. I need to work with it. For example, I need to have the sum of the values.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your requirement correctly. Actually you can get the list, store it to `StreamBuilder`, then handle it with `if-else` condition. Change the widget based on the condition.

Comment: OK, I will try it and I will post the result I will obtain. Thank you!

Comment: You could use a bool variable like ''fetching=true". Fetch data in init metchod and setstate "fetching=false". Inside build method show a circular progress bar when fetching == true else show your actual build logic. Better solution is to use a stream builder.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved with `StreamBuilder` and `if`-`else` conditions.